# How to serialize a UIView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization, uiview

Is it possible to serialize a `UIView` object? If yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 12):

`UIView` implements the `NSCoding` protocol, so you can use `encodeWithCoder:` to get a serialized representation, and `initWithCoder:` to reconstitute a `UIView` from such a representation. You can find a lot of details in the [Serializations Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html).

Here is quick example of how to do it:

```
- (NSData *)dataForView:(UIView *)view {
  NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
  NSKeyedArchiver  *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
  [archiver encodeObject:view forKey:@"view"];
  [archiver finishEncoding];
  [archiver release];

  return (id)data;
}

- (UIView *)viewForData:(NSData *)data {
  NSKeyedUnarchiver  *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];

  UIView *view = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
  [unarchiver finishDecoding];
  [unarchiver release];

  return view;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are actually using a custom subclass of UIView, you'll need to override encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: to add your own properties.

Comment: i think you mean "NSKeyedUnarchiver  *unarchiver" and not "NSKeyedArchiver  *unarchiver". whilst they are both descended from NSCoding, they aren't the same thing. it still "works" but nanny XCode nags, as she should, in other less trivial instances.

Comment: UIImageView conforms to NSCoding.  I am not sure when the switch happened but my iOS app (iOS 5) has no issue with archiving a UIImageView.  Probably iOS 5.