# iOS 8 - Action Extension returning UIView

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios8, ios8-extension

I'm working on an Action Extension with no UI

`NSExtensionPointIdentifier : com.apple.services`

I'm trying to complete my extension returning an UIView

```
MYExternalView *viewTest = [[MYExternalView alloc] init];

NSItemProvider *resultsProvider = [[NSItemProvider alloc] initWithItem:viewTest typeIdentifier:kUTTypeMyCustomType];

NSExtensionItem *resultsItem = [[NSExtensionItem alloc] init];
resultsItem.attachments = @[resultsProvider];

[self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[resultsItem] completionHandler:nil];
```

My returning view `MYExternalView` extends `NSSecureCoding` with very simple code:

```
MYExternalView.h


@interface MYExternalView : UIView < NSSecureCoding >


@end




MYExternalView.m


@implementation MYExternalView

+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Running this code i had error message

```
<Warning>: <NSXPCConnection: 0x17410ae60> connection to service named com.*******.****.****: Warning: Exception caught during decoding of received message, dropping incoming message.
    Exception: Exception while decoding argument 0 (#2 of invocation):
    <NSInvocation: 0x174262580>
    return value: {v} void
    target: {@} 0x0
    selector: {:} _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:
    argument 2: {@} 0x0
    argument 3: {@} 0x0
    argument 4: {@?} 0x0 (block)
```

Some ideas to solve my problem?

If i return another kind of object, a string for instance, everything work well.

Thanks.

Comment: It may support secure coding, but you are not secure coding it. Wouldn't it be better if you did? Passing around a UIView like this is dubious; passing around an NSData is not.

Comment: that's great, i can try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169061/how-to-serialize-a-uiview