# How to get back the control on embedded text on a UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, text, uiimage

I work on a swift application that allows to take a picture and embeds some text on it (for example: the current date). I have some labels (containing the current date, for example) appearing on the screen when I take my picture.

Thanks to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906914/how-do-i-add-text-to-an-image-in-ios-swift/30185702#30185702), I succeeded at embedding my text on my UIImage. Now, when I load my image in another ViewController, I want to permit the user to move the text with his finger on the image and to change its color, so I need to get back the control on my block of text. How can I do it ? Can somebody please give me some help ?

I think there might be some clue in the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom view inherit from UIView
2. Add a subview to it and keed a reference on this subview (UILabel, UITextView, etc.)
3. Use touch-handling methods from UIView to move your subview to the tapped positon.

for example :

```
class MyCustomView : UIView {
    var backgroundImage: UIImageView!
    var dateLabel: UILabel!

    init() {
        // ... do job to handle image and create subviews
    }

    func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
         if let aTouch = touches.first {
              dateLabel.position = aTouch.locationInView(self)
         }
    }
}
```

This code need to be fullfilled but you have an algorithm and an example.

Vincent

Comment: Of course, I missed out a point, you can render a view to export it as a UIImage and save it as JPG/PNG with usual methods

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I finally changed my mind and decided to embed the text only once the user moved it and clicked on the "done" button on my UI. Therefore, the user can only move my labels once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing text on the image and saving it to disk as a JPG/PNG file, you can create a `UIView` with a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` in it. Saving the `UIView` as an image in the Camera roll means taking a snapshot of the view and saving that to disk in your desired image format; but at the same time, also save to disk the exact same `UIView` using `NSKeyedArchiver`.

That way, you can inflate the `UIView` from `NSKeyedUnarchiver` whenever you need to make the "image" (which is a `UIView`) editable again.

See:

[How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)

[How to serialize a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169061/how-to-serialize-a-uiview)

Comment: Thanks, the first link you gave to me has been very helpful.